# Cypress error infinite loading and console error also

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, loading

When I open Cypress it gets in an infinite loading loop.

[image]

I also can see the following error on the promp:

```
√  Verified Cypress! C:\...\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.1\Cypress

Opening Cypress...

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '"C:/.../AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/10.3.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/register_ts_node.js"'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:12)
    at preloadModules (internal/bootstrap/node.js:601:7)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:273:9)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Also when I first open cypress it takes a lot of time, more than 3 minutes... but the first time it opens OK

```
npx cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 10.3.1

✔  Verified Cypress! C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.3.1\Cypress

Opening Cypress...
```

[image]+

after clicking on continue in this screen is when the error appears

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try clearing the cache from your `C:\...\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache`

Comment: does removing cypress.config from your project help? In my case cypress then loads but crashes again later

Comment: @raju, clean the cache did not work :(. I get the same error and infinite loading

Comment: @fly_over_32 neither removing the cypress.config. I have deleted all node_modules and package-lock.json and then npm install and same error

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

Solution founded.

I was usisng node v11 and it must be version 14... Sorry